# How to setup string to float converters for numpy genfromtxt

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I found many ways to input csv files with text entries as numerical arrays in Python such as [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html) and [this](http://penandpants.com/2012/03/09/reading-text-tables-with-python/), but none were the situation I have and none worked for me.  I also couldn't find the answer in [the manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) of numpy or other common tools for doing this, but maybe it's there and I just can't understand it.

I have data in a csv like this:

```
"experiment 1"
"var1","var2","var3","var4","var5"
"7","0","1","3","1"
"8","4","3","1","1"
"8","5","3","3","1"
"8","6","3","3","3"
```

I tried reading in the data using

```
dataArray = np.genfromtxt('Input Data/'+fileName,delimiter=',',skiprows=2)
```

and I also tried adding

```
.astype(np.float)
```

to the end.  But what I end up with in either case is:

```
[[ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
[ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
[ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
[ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]]
```

because converting strings found in numeric columns into nan is what genfromtxt is supposed to do according to the documentation.  There is also a `converters` parameter to `genfromtxt`, but the only example I could find of using it is from the documentation:

```
converters = {3: lambda s: float(s or 0)}
```

and I really can't make any sense of that syntax.  Assuming that the built-in converters can handle my data, what is the correct syntax for writing the converter parameter for that?  If the converters can't do what I need, does anybody know how to read this data in?  I expected this to be super simple, something I would find in 5 minutes, but I've wasted hours on this now.

Comment: Maybe, you should consider renaming your question, because I think it's more about how to read your datafile to a numpy array, right? Float converters are just one possibility it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reading the data in with the column names**

To use `np.genfromtext` you should first read the file into a string, delete all `"` characters and then read this string making use of `cStringIO`:

```
>>>import cStringIO
>>>with open ("123", "r") as myfile:
       data=myfile.read().replace('"', '')
>>>np.genfromtxt(cStringIO.StringIO(data), skip_header=1, delimiter=",", names = True)

array([(7.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0),
       (8.0, 4.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0),
       (8.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0),
       (8.0, 6.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0)], 
      dtype=[('var1', '<f8'), ('var2', '<f8'), ('var3', '<f8'), ('var4', '<f8'), ('var5', '<f8')])
```

You can also use `pandas`:

```
>>>pd.read_csv(file, header=0, skiprows = 1).as_matrix()

   var1  var2  var3  var4  var5
0     7     0     1     3     1
1     8     4     3     1     1
2     8     5     3     3     1
3     8     6     3     3     3
```

**Reading the data in without the column names**

You could first read the file to an array containing strings:

```
a = np.genfromtxt('filename', skip_header=2, delimiter=",", dtype = 'str')
print a
```

which gives:

```
[['"7"' '"0"' '"1"' '"3"' '"1"']
 ['"8"' '"4"' '"3"' '"1"' '"1"']
 ['"8"' '"5"' '"3"' '"3"' '"1"']
 ['"8"' '"6"' '"3"' '"3"' '"3"']]
```

and then convert it to floats using numpy like this:

```
a = np.char.strip(a, '"').astype(float)
print a
```

which gives

```
[[ 7.  0.  1.  3.  1.]
 [ 8.  4.  3.  1.  1.]
 [ 8.  5.  3.  3.  1.]
 [ 8.  6.  3.  3.  3.]]
```

You also suggested to use pandas. To read it in a pandas DataFrame you could do:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv('./test', header=None, skiprows = 2)
print a
```

which gives:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  7  0  1  3  1
1  8  4  3  1  1
2  8  5  3  3  1
3  8  6  3  3  3
```

Comment: Okay, that's close, and easier to use than the per column converter.  Here's what actually did it: `dataArray = np.char.strip(np.genfromtxt('Input Data/'+fileName, skip_header=2, delimiter=",", dtype = None), '"').astype(float)` which combines the two lines you have and changes some parts that weren't quite right.  The only probably with this is that it also CANNOT handle the headers: putting instead `skip_header=1, names=True,` returns `TypeError: string operation on non-string array` even when I reinsert `, deletechars='"', dtype = 'str'`.  I'm going to avoid pandas for now.

Comment: OK, didn't know you also want to read the names. I think you cannot do this with genfromtxt because your file has different separators for the column names and for the data entries. You possibly could do that with `pandas.read_csv` because there you can specify multiple delimiters via regular expressions.

Comment: Ah, the real data has matching headers -- the variable names for each column. I've updated the question to reflect this.  It should be a fairly normal thing to do so I expect `genfromtxt` to be able to handle it for a person who knows how it works.  `deletechars='"'` should actually be taking care of this, but it doesn't seem to do anything.  Maybe the best thing would be to open the csv as a block of txt and remove the `"`, then run `genfromtxt`.

Comment: I agree. I updated the answer accordingly. Btw: It's really easy with `pandas`, maybe you should have a look.

Answer (score 4):

After more searching and trying and fighting I managed to find out one way to do this.

First, for convenience, I make a conversion formula separately and call it from within the `genfromtxt` command:

```
convert = lambda x: float(x.strip('"') or -999)
```

What this [lambda function](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk) does is strip the double quotes characters from each entry (or if it's empty or `nan` set it as `-999`) and then convert the entry into a float.  Then it goes into the `genfromtext` command like this:

```
dataArray = np.genfromtxt('Input Data/'+fileName,delimiter=',',skip_header=2,converters={0: convert,1: convert,2: convert,3: convert,4: convert},dtype=None)
```

This works for this particular case, but it has two problems: **(1) you have to specify the converter for every column separately -- I couldn't find a way to specify "apply to all columns".**  A better way to do this would be to use an iterated function that goes over all columns and applies the conversion to all of them...then THAT function would specify which columns to apply it to. I don't know how to do that if that's possible. Problem **(2) is that you can't read in the headers in combination with the converters.**  For example:

```
dataArray = np.genfromtxt('Input Data/'+fileName,delimiter=',',skip_header=1,names=True,converters={0: convert,1: convert,2: convert,3: convert,4: convert},dtype=None)
```

should work if the row above your data has column headers, but when the names are read in from the column it's no longer an array, but rather a list of tuples.  This is probably because the column names in the data also have quotes around them and the converter isn't being applied to them.  That should NOT matter because they are not part of the array, which is all numbers, but that seems to be how `genfromtxt` works.  Which is to say it doesn't seem to be a very good/robust method for performing this task, and of course it's poorly documented so it's not clear what it can or can't do and how to get the method to do those things.

My recommendation for somebody facing this problem in the future is to look to a different method to perform this function.  Many people recommended `pandas` for similar tasks in other questions, but I don't know if it is better for this case.  For now this will work for me, but in the nearish future it will have to be replaced with a more robust csv reader to produce a file format that numpy can readily build into an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
this will print you first two columns in the file
Since you have two headers you need to skip first to rows with next()

with open("data.csv", 'r') as f:
        r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        next(r, None)  # skip the header
        next(r, None)  # skip the header
        for row in r:
            print(row[0],row[1])

7 0
8 4
8 5
8 6
```

Comment: I believe the parameter `skiprows=2` is suppose to handle that.

Comment: @AaronBramson you mean np? this is plain csv reader, it does not have skiprows parameter, I have just searched csv module help. at least in python 3.5 no skiprows ...

Comment: yes, in the end it needs to be a numpy array, so it seems the best thing should be to use numpy's built-in methods to do this.  And `genfromtxt` is supposed to be the right one...if I can just figure out the converters.  Another alternative would be to remove the quotation marks from the csv file before reading, but using the converters should be more general and therefore preferred.

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

> converters = {3: lambda s: float(s or 0)} 
>   and I really can't make any sense of that syntax

from the [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) documentation:

> converters : dict, optional
>   A dictionary mapping column number to a function that will convert that column to a float. E.g., if column 0 is a date string: converters = {0: datestr2num}. Converters can also be used to provide a default value for missing data (but see also genfromtxt): converters = {3: lambda s: float(s.strip() or 0)}. Default: None

So in the example:

> converters = {3: lambda s: float(s or 0)}

that means that converters is a python dictionary (the literal for a dictionary in python is {key: value], example

```
dict_example = {1: "the position is 1"}
```

where the key is 1 and the value is "the position is 1".

Converters is a dictionary, where the key is the number of the column in the file, and the value is the **transformation** that will be applied to each element of that column. Functions are denoted also in Python with **lambda** (technically they are anonymous functions, look elsewhere for the documentation)

So

> converters = {3: lambda s: float(s or 0)}

defines a converters as a dictionary, where the key refers to column 3, then apply to each element of that column the function *float*.

Another trick is the *float* function with the *or* inside. Here what we are using is the [shortcircuit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) of the *or* operator.

If s is null, or not a number (see more details [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)), the for *or* results in false, and *false* with *0*, results in *0*. So it is a concise form of converting anything that is not a number (even missing) to 0. If *s* is a string, or shortcircuits and returns *s*

Answer (score 0):

I found a two solutions.
1. Using converters
2. Using excel or LibreCalc.

1. converters worked for me but they use dictionaries so you have to specify each column. Useful for preserving specific columns when they are strings but other than that not a great solution.

```
    import numpy as np;

myConverters = {}
myConverters[0] = lambda s:float(s.decode('ascii').strip('"')); #column zero is a number
myConverters[1] = lambda s:s; #column 1 is a string

filename = 'Spread of Disease population-density-table.csv';

data = np.genfromtxt(filename, skip_header= 6, #skip_footer=10, 
                     delimiter= ",", 
                     #names= True,
                     #dtype= str,
                     converters = myConverters,

                     )
print(data)
```

2. A simpler solution was to open the file in LibreCalc (excel) and save as .csv. This saves the file in the standard (no ") format.

After this it is business as usual.